# How can I enable spell check in Rider?

Tags: c#, rider

When I type something like `Console.WriteLine("helllllo worllll!")`, IntelliJ IDEA will show green wavy lines under the word `helllllo` and `worllll`, but Rider won't. I've searched `typo`/`spell` using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, but I didn't get any helpful results.

So here comes the question, how can I enable spell checks in Rider?

Comment: You will have to wait for a plug-in to be developed.

Comment: This plugin might help:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9931-typo-fixer

It's a typo fixer, and it can detect typo.

Comment: And you can vote for this issue in their bug tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-2392

Comment: Luckily, we'll have spell checker in Rider since 2018.2 EAP 1 according to RIDER-2392.

Answer (score 1):

Rider 2018.2 added ReSpeller (the spell-checking you are looking for).

More info on https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2018/07/10/integrated-spell-checking-respeller-resharper-rider/